# ../../../public/js/filename.js Is my path is there any shortcut for defining path that points home in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

JS folder is public and views are in `resources` both are in home folder.

How to create a variable that points to home so that I don't need to write backslashes again

Answer (score 0):

you can use `asset()` helper.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/filename.js') }}"></script>
```